# Google sheets auto log sign ins/outs

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

All of our users have a Google email account. We also have an office sign in/out Google form that populates a spreadsheet that is displayed on our Google site page so the boss can see who is in the office. This is owned by our office Google account but can be edited by anyone in our office (with their own Google accounts). After signing into Google email, users have to fill out the sign in/out form.

Is there any way for the Google email sign in & out to get logged automatically to a Google Sheet? This would eliminate the need for our users to use the Google form.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: I assumed this would need to be accomplished using a script.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get users sign in / out using the [reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/) but checking where that sign in / out event happened is far more complicated.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like I need Google Admin rights for all this which is not going to happen. This is for someone who might come across this thread and has the permissions - here's instructions - https://support.google.com/a/answer/4580120?hl=en